# XCode 3 -> 4 confusion

Tags: xcode

I've just upgraded from OSX 10.6 -> 10.8. I had XCode 3.2.6 installed and I installed 4.5 through the appstore. I appear to have both versions installed now (which I don't mind) but I'm lost as to where everything lives now, /Developer doesn't seem to have anything new in it.

Also, my commandline tools like svn have stopped working now, they are not found. I know XCode 4 has newer and better tools (newer SVN, Git, etc) but how do I get it set up nicely? I thought cmd-line tools were part of the XCode 4 installation.

Uninstalling 3.2.6 is fine if needed, I just want to avoid clashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific questions, Xcode 4.5 is in your Applications folder. It is packaged as a single app instead of using the /Developer folder. Xcode 3.2.6 is in your /Developer folder. You can keep both versions installed.

Xcode 4.5 does not install the command line tools initially. You can install them from Xcode's Downloads preferences. You can also install them by choosing Xcode > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools.

Comment: Is there any obvious reason why installing 4.5 seems to have _removed_ the command line tools I had before?

Comment: I don't know why. All I know is you can have multiple versions of Xcode installed, but only one version of Xcode's command line tools installed on one machine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look up any transition guides for moving from Xcode 3 to 4. There are lots of different features, so it may take a while to get used to the new layout and where Xcode puts things.

Try these links for starters:

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/transitioning_from_xcode_3_to_xcode_4

http://beginning-mac-programming.timisted.net/xcode-4-general-overview.html